# Best Approximate Solution of Heat Equation (Diffusive Logistic Equation)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, approximation, heat-equation

If $u(x,t) \ge 0$ in the domain $ (0 \times 1) \times (0,\infty)$, find a function that caps the value of $u(x,t)$ in the region $(0 \times 1) \times (0,T)$. $u(x,t)$ is a solution of the following system:
\begin{cases} 
u_t = u_{xx} + u(1-u), & (0 \times 1) \times (0,\infty) \\ 
u(0,t) = 0 = u(1,t), & t \in (0,\infty)\\
u(x,0) = sin(\pi x), & x \in (0,1) 
\end{cases}
**My attempt:** I notice that without the term $u(1-u)$, the solution is simply a heat equation. So $u(x,t) \le ||u(x,0)|| = 1$. Adding in the effect of the term $u(1-u)$, which is positive on the interval $(0,1)$, 
then the following approximation can be made on $(0 \times 1) \times (0,T)$,
$$u(x,t) \le 1 + ||u(1-u)||T$$

This is not a very strong approximation. So I am looking for something stronger. I appreciate any input. Thank you.

Comment: Wov, you solved the Fisher's equation using the Duhamel's principle? :)

Comment: @Artem I doubt it. I probably did something wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is a nonlinear equation, and there is no formula that solves it. The exercise probably asks you to show that your solution will be always between 0 and 1 (note that 0 and 1) solve it

Comment: @Artem The actual exercise actually wants me to find the sharpest possible estimate for this system (diffusive logistic pde). But I am not sure how to obtain the sharpest one.

Comment: Would a perturbative approach be helpful?

Comment: @RonGordon Yes, I would appreciate a perturbation approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to assume that the function is two times differentiable with continuous second derivatives then the problem can be completed as follows.

Consider any finite value of $T > 0$ and concentrate on the restriction $u_T$ of $u$ to the rectangle \begin{equation} R_T = [0,1] \times [0,T]. \end{equation} By continuity, $u$ will assume its maximum value on this rectangle. There are now three distinct possibilities:

1. The maximum is assumed somewhere on the parabolic boundary. On the initial line \begin{equation} u(x,0)=\sin(\pi x) \end{equation} is bounded by 1 and equality is achieved at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Since the boundary conditions are homogeneous, the maximum is not assumed there on the lines $x=0$ or $x=1$.
2. The maximum is assumed in the interior of $R_T$, i.e the rectangle \begin{equation} R'_T = (0,1) \times (0,T). \end{equation} In this case \begin{equation} u_t = u_x = 0, \quad \text{(critical point)} \end{equation} and \begin{equation} u_{xx} \leq 0 \quad \text{(maximum)}. \end{equation} It follows from the differential equation that $u(1-u) \geq 0$ which implies that $u \in [0,1]$.
3. The maximum is assumed on the line $t=T$. In this case \begin{equation} u_t \ge 0 \end{equation} or there would be an even larger value inside $R'_T$ (Taylor expansion). Moreover, by considering the restriction of $u$ to the line $t=T$ we deduce that \begin{equation} u_x = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad u_{xx} \leq 0. \end{equation} By rewriting the differential equation as \begin{equation} u_t - u_{xx} = u(1-u) \end{equation} we conclude that the right hand side must be nonnegative, because the left hand side is nonnegative. It follows again that $u \in [0,1]$.

Since $u$ assumes the value $1$ on the initial line, we conclude that $u \leq 1$ is the best possible upper bound for $u$ across the entire domain.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is wonderful! I just have one small question, in scenario 1, how can we conclude that if maximum is on the parabolic boundary then $u \le 1$?

Comment: @Tin Phan: The function values are prescribed on the parabolic boundary. I am not sure that the term is standard in English literature. I was taught parabolic equations in Danish. The parabolic boundary is the union of the initial line and the left and right boundaries of the domain. I have added a few lines extending case 1 and cleaned up the formatting. If you can get hold of Fritz John's text: "Partial Differential Equations" you will see similar reasoning applied to derive maximum principles for the heat equation.

Comment: Once again. Thank you very much.